# check if message has an attachment in Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to create a function that will only proceed if a message has an image attached to it. What is the best way to check if a message has an image attached to it? Pseudocode would look something like this:

```
if message has attachement:
     do this
else:
     do other thing
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an [`attachments`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.attachments) attribute of all the Message objects, you can just use  -

```
if message.attachments: # if message has an attachment(s)
     #do stuff
if not message.attachments: # if message doesnt have an attachment(s)
    #do stuff
```

---

Reference

- https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.attachments